# Regular Expression with specific required numbers on both sides of decimal point

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, regex

I am trying to figure out a regular expression for an asp.net RequiredFieldValidator that validates decimal values from 1.001 to 99.9999.

This means every value greater than or equal to 1.001 and less than or equal to 99.9999.

The closest I have managed is:

```
(?=\d+(?:\.\d+)?$)(?![0\.]+$).{1,7}$
```

This still allows 0.1 and 1.0001, how do I prevent these values?

Comment: Could you clarify how many numbers you want to allow in different situations? Is it `# to the right == # to the left + 2` or what?

Comment: Just every number greater than or equal to 1.001 and less than or equal to 99.9999!

Comment: You're right, you did make that clear. \o/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use negative lookaheads for that task:

```
^0*(?!1(?:\.0+)?$)(?!1\.000)(?!99\.9999.*[1-9])[1-9][0-9]?(?:\.[0-9]+)?$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/kX0rP0/3)**

Comment: Very close, but did not allow me to have valid numbers without a decimal point, i.e. 1, 2 or 99. I added a bit on the end that I think achieves this: ^(?!1\.0+$)(?!1\.000)(?!99\.9999.*[1-9])[1-9][0-9]?\.[0-9]+|[0-9]{1,2}$

Comment: @Paddy I will modify shortly, BTW, `1` shouldn't be valid, right?

Comment: That's right! Only thing I'm left trying to fix now is leading 0's
01 should work

Comment: Does not allow 1, or a 1 with any leading 0's

Comment: @Paddy I don't understand how does 1 fit into `1.001 to 99.9999` range?

Comment: I confused myself, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know asp.net, but maybe you could use something like this?

```
[1-9][0-9]?\.[0-9]{2}[1-9][0-9]?
```

However, maybe converting this to float and checking its inside the interval would do the trick, without the use of regexp...